# Make child div's width grow at the same rate as parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with several nested divs.  All the child div's are float:left so they are all on the same line.  The parent div "newDistractor" has a width of 100% so as it's parent grows it does as well.  All of the child nodes have fixed widths of 20px.  I want the div "distractorText" to grow at the same rate as it's parent so it occupies all empty space.  Any ideas how to do it.

```
<div class="newDistractor">
    <div style="width:20px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="width:20px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="distractorText">Enter text to add option.</div>
    <div style="width:20px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="width:20px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="clear:left;margin-bottom:-43px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work. It doesn't actually resize the `distractorText` `div`, but it might be what you need:

```
<div class="newDistractor">
    <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="distractorText">Enter text to add option.</div>
    <div style="clear:left;margin-bottom:-43px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

The CSS for it is basically:

```
.left { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }
```

Look at it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VfrLG/)

**edit** I cleaned the jsfiddle a little: look [now](http://jsfiddle.net/VfrLG/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) and then each time count the number of children `<div>`s, divide it into the current width, and set accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For this example specifically, you could use margins instead of floating `&nbsp;` `div` elements.

```
<div class="newDistractor">
    <div class="distractorText" style="margin:0px 40px;">Enter text to add option.</div>
    <div style="clear:left;margin-bottom:-43px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this right-off, but if you set the width of class "distractorText" to `100%`, it should take care of the issue... or to some other "acceptable" percentage (maybe 50).

Answer (score 0):

All religious crusades put aside, the following HTML will do what you need ^L^ :

```
<table class="newDistractor" style="width:100%">
    <td style="width:20px">a</td>
    <td style="width:20px">b</td>
    <td class="distractorText" style="width:100%">Enter text to add option.</td>
    <td style="width:20px">c</td>
    <td style="width:20px">d</td>
    <td style="clear:left;margin-bottom:-43px;">e</td>
</table>
```